# Ng-table not calling get data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ngtable

I've got implemented ng-table with an ajax call but never call the function from getdata, the function onBuscarTable is never call, I've look at the debbugger console to check it and dosen't call it:

what i'm doing whrong?

here's the js:

```
    $scope.onBuscarTable = function ($defer, params) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Home/GetEfficiencyDetails',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //data: JSON.stringify({ title: "fghfdhgfdgfd" }),
        success: function (data) {
            $scope.items = data;
            $defer.resolve(data);
        }
    });
};

//$scope.getEffiencyDetails();
$scope.tableBuscar = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1, // show first page
    count: $scope.items.length, // hides pager
    sorting: {
        name: 'asc' // initial sorting
    }
}, {
    counts: [], // hides page sizes
    getData: $scope.onBuscarTable

});

$scope.tableBuscar.reload();
```

and here is the html:

```
                            <table ng-table="tableBuscar" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">

                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="5">Battery Life</th>
                                    <th colspan="4">SBC</th>
                                    <th colspan="3">ZBC</th>
                                    <th>Overall</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Pool #</th>
                                    <th>True Cap.</th>
                                    <th>Util.</th>
                                    <th>Load Sharing</th>

                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                                    <td>{{item.PoolName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.AvgTrueCapacity}}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.AvgEnergyUsageDaily}}</td>  
                                </tr>                                  

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: why you are using $.ajax instead of $http service from angularjs

Comment: I use that in another project and it works well

Comment: i would prefer you to use $http service instead of $.ajax and also you should not mix jquery with angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You code should using `$http` instead of `$.ajax`

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.onBuscarTable = function($defer, params) {
    $http.get('/Home/GetEfficiencyDetails').success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
        $defer.resolve(data);
    });
};

//$scope.getEffiencyDetails();
$scope.tableBuscar = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1, // show first page
    count: $scope.items.length, // hides pager
    sorting: {
        name: 'asc' // initial sorting
    }
}, {
    counts: [], // hides page sizes
    getData: $scope.onBuscarTable

});

$scope.tableBuscar.reload();
```

Comment: it works but it's call three times, why can it be that?
GET http://localhost:4684/Home/GetEfficiencyDetails 200 OK 
GET http://localhost:4684/Home/GetEfficiencyDetails 200 OK 
GET http://localhost:4684/Home/GetEfficiencyDetails 200 OK

Comment: because using jquery inside angular will not run angular digest, you need to manually update it..

Comment: @DiegoUnanue its calling multiple time because `$scope.tableBuscar.reload();` this line